# Question about Associates in $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Two elements $a,b\in R$ are associates in $R$ if $a=bu$ where $u$ is a unit in $\mathbb R$.

My question is: If we take $\mathbb Q$ to be $R$. Then are all elements in $Q$ associates? If so, then is this true for any field?

Comment: Not exactly: all elements of $\mathbf Q^*$ are associates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so this applies to all Fields $F-\{0\}$, correct? @Bernard

Comment: Yes, absolutely.